# Getting Attachments From Outlook 2010 With Python

Tags: python-2.7, outlook-2010, pywin32, win32com

I have the following script, which is trying to get attachments from Outlook.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(0)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast() #open last message
attachments = message.Attachments #assign attachments to attachment variable
attachment = attachments.Item(1)
attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join('c:', 'temp'))
```

When I run it however I am getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/e003048/QA/trunk/automation/selenium/src/global_functions/util_get_email_attachments.py", line 11, in <module>
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(0)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 522, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Outlook.Application.GetDefaultFolder
```

I am unsure where I would put the username to get this to work.

I tried the suggestion in the answer below and am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "C:/Users/e003048/QA/trunk/automation/selenium/src/global_functions/util_get_email_attachments.py", line 10, in <module>
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(0)
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in GetDefaultFolder
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)
```

**I wanted to include my completed working code in-case anyone else will find it useful:**

```
def get_email_attachments(self):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace('MAPI')
    # change the Folders parameter to the directory you are having the attachment go to
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('ForAttachments')
    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetLast()  # opens the last message
    attachments = message.Attachments
    attachment = attachments.Item(1)
    attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\temp\\' + attachment.FileName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetDefaultFolder` is not defined on the application object (see [application docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application_properties%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), it is defined on the `NameSpace` object which you get via

```
mapi = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
```

Then

```
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(0)
```

I think you can also use

```
mapi = outlook.Session
```

instead of `GetNameSpace`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and edited my question with the second error I am getting after doing this.

Comment: @DarthOpto how do you know 0 is valid value

Comment: Thank you, this is working, apparently the inbox is not 0, but 6